# setSomeState() called from a catch() function doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

If have a problem with react code where, for some reason, everything works as expected when I update the UI from the `MyApp.promise().then(<here>)` but not in my `MyApp.promise().then().catch(<here>)`

- I know the code is actually executed up to the point I actually call `setData` which is my `useState()` returned function
- A call to that function in `then()` works just fine, not in `catch()`
- the exception that eventually triggers `catch()` works fine since the `catch()` is executed as expected
- I added a `console.log()` inside my component, and I see that it's no longer re-drawn when the updates comes from `catch()`

I guess my question is : what would be special in a `catch()` function so react wouldn't behave ?

This is the code for my application hook that handles upgrade status updates :

```js
const useUpdateStatus = () => {
    const [data,setData] = useState({status: STATUS.IDLE,changelog:null,tasks:[]})

    const updateData = (d) => {
        // We call setData with an anonymous function so we can merge previous
        // data with new data
        setData((prev) => {
            console.log({ ...prev, ...d })
            return { ...prev, ...d }
        })
    };

    // Only once, we set the timer to periodically update status
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            MyApp.get('/system/upgrade')
            .then((upgrade) => {
                // If anything is not "pending", it means we are upgrading
                for (var t of upgrade.tasks) {
                    if (t.status !== "pending") {
                        updateData({ status: STATUS.INSTALLING})
                    }
                }
                // updateData will call setData with the full status

                // This works as intended, UI is updated on each step
                updateData({ tasks: upgrade.tasks, changelog: upgrade.changelog})
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                // If data can't be fetched, it probably means we are restarting
                // services, so we updated the tasks array accordingly
                setData((prev) => {
                    for (var t of prev.tasks) {
                        if (t['id'] === "restarting") {
                            t['status'] = 'running'
                        }
                        else if (t['status'] == "running") {
                            t['status'] = 'finished'
                        }
                    }
                    // The expected data is logged here
                    console.log(prev)
                    return prev
                })
            })
        }, 1000);
    },[])
    return data
}
```

This is the presentation layer :

```js
// Using the hook :
const { changelog, tasks, status } = useUpdateStatus()

// Somewhere int he page :
<UpdateProgress tasks={tasks}/>

// The actual components :
const UpdateProgress = (props) => {
    return(
        <div style={{display: "flex", width: "100%"}}>
            { props.tasks.map(s => {
                return(
                    <UpdateTask key={s.name} task={s}/>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

const UpdateTask = (props) => {
    const colors = {
        "pending":"LightGray",
        "running":"SteelBlue",
        "finished":"Green",
        "failed":"red"
    }
    return(
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center",  flex: "1" }}>
                <Check fill={colors[props.task.status]} width="50px" height="50px"/><br/>
                <p style={props.task.status==="running" ? {fontWeight: 'bold'} : { fontWeight: 'normal'}}>{props.task.name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React performs an `Object.is` comparison to check is a re-render is needed after a state update call. Since you are mutating the state in catch block, react is falsely notified that the state hasn't changed and hence a re-render in not triggered

You can update your state like below to make it work

```
 .catch((e) => {
            // If data can't be fetched, it probably means we are restarting
            // services, so we updated the tasks array accordingly
            setData((prev) => {
                for (var t of prev.tasks) {
                    if (t['id'] === "restarting") {
                        t['status'] = 'running'
                    }
                    else if (t['status'] == "running") {
                        t['status'] = 'finished'
                    }
                }
                // The expected data is logged here
                console.log(prev)
                return {...prev}
            })
        })
```

However a better way to update state is to do it in an immutable manner

```
  .catch((e) => {
            // If data can't be fetched, it probably means we are restarting
            // services, so we updated the tasks array accordingly
            setData((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                tasks: prev.tasks.map((task) => {
                    if (task.id === "restarting") {
                        return { ...task, status: 'running'}
                    }
                    else if (task.id === "running") {
                        return { ...task, status: 'finished'}
                    }
                    return task
                })
            }))
        })
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it works indeed. If only I understood why !

So you said I'm mutating state : does that mean I'm returning a new, modified object ? i.e. the ref to that object is different and as the original wasn't modified, react doesn't rerender ?

Comment: what I mean by mutation is that you modifying the statee object at the same reference, for state updates you should create a new reference. Do read about immutability in javascript

Comment: Ha, that’s the opposite then, an update needs to be a different object and I was just mutating the one returned. 

You saved my day, and I’ll definitely hunt some immutability literature !